# Fail to boot into any kernel after update to 5.4.0-54 on Ubuntu with Threadripper 3xxx

Tags: boot, upgrade, kernel

I'm [back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240114/how-can-i-get-ubuntu-20-04-to-boot-on-threadripper-3990x). I recently let apt apply some updates and tried restarting. This time I have symptoms similar to [this recent question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291486/boot-crash-after-latest-update-of-intel-microcode-nov-11-2020), but I don't have an Intel processor.

- GRUB menu shows me options for kernels 5.4.0-52, -53, and -54.
- Choosing any of them does the same thing: normal behavior up to the point of asking me for the password to decrypt my hard drive, then unresponsive black screen after entering it. Only response I get after that point is when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd>, which brings up a splash screen with a 5-dot "spinner" while it shuts down, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> drops me into a terminal login.
- That means choosing the oldest kernel does not give me a working system.
- I can boot into recovery mode for any kernel just fine.
- `dpkg -l | grep linux-image` shows `ii` status for all images. In fact, `dpkg -l` shows `ii` or `rc` for all packages.
- `dpkg --configure -a` does nothing.
- `update-grub` finishes successfully but fixes nothing.
- `apt upgrade` and `apt dist-upgrade` do nothing except print a list of packages "automatically installed and no longer required", which includes exactly the oldest kernel and an Nvidia driver:

  - `libnvidia-compute-435`
  - `linux-headers-5.4.0-52`
  - `linux-headers-5.4.0-52-generic`
  - `linux-image-5.4.0-52-generic`
  - `linux-modules-5.4.0-52-generic`
  - `linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-52-generic`

This worries me. In the past I've been able to safely boot into the oldest kernel while I figure out what's wrong with the installation of the newest kernel. If my machine thinks my oldest kernel can be removed, maybe something in it was corrupted?

If I "resume normal boot" from recovery mode, it drops me into a terminal login prompt.

How can I figure out what's going wrong behind the black screen? I don't have any error message to look up.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the desktop fixed my problem:

```
apt install --reinstall ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Here's a bunch of commands I tried before that one that didn't fix the problem on their own, but may have set it up to succeed:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt dist-upgrade
apt install --reinstall linux-image-5.4.0-52-generic
apt install --reinstall libnvidia-compute-435
```

After I could log in, I noticed my internet wasn't working. Turns out Network Manager stopped managing the connections. The last step of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/882812/538768) fixed that problem, by clearing the contents of the file `/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf`.